# track clicks on external website

Tags: google-analytics, web, event-tracking

Is it possible to track clicks on other websites, which I have no ownership? The Google analytics can be used to track the activities on my own website. But I would need to track if user clicked on the link on an external website.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not track external websites. However you can track an event, if the user clicks on a link on your homepage which leads to an external page. Or you can track the referral information, which tells you where the user came from.

Comment: Is it possible to track the external site if I display it within my own webpage ,say in an Iframe?

Comment: You can track whether the User saw the iframe or not, but everything within the iframe is not sharing any information with your site.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to track outbound link clicks is with [autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) using its [`outboundLinkTracker`](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/outbound-link-tracker.md) plugin.

Comment: While autotrack is utterly brilliant it will (of course) not track clicks on the third party website, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether the OP is actually asking to track "clicks on" or whether they mistyped and really meant "clicks to" :)

Comment: @PhilipWalton i mean clicks ON :)

Comment: In that case it's a definite **no**. If you could track clicks on other websites, what would stop you from tracking key stokes? Then you could steal people's passwords.